# What do the cabin bells mean on airplanes?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft

When traveling by air, it's common to hear bells, chimes, tones, whatever-you-call-them over the speaker system. It seems like a single tone is just a passenger pushing their call button. But what do the other ones mean? Are they unique to each airline, or are they universal country-wide or world-wide?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right, firstly according to [Airliners.net forums](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/print.main?id=1301544), each airline has different chime meanings.

However, on [Yahoo](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080214142154AARyHif), we have a list of all of the chimes - but presumably it's for a specific plane, and it doesn't say which:

Generally they are as follows:-

> 1 x chime for a passenger call bell
>
> 2 x chimes if the crew are calling each other
>
> 2 x chimes to indicate takeoff and landing
>
> 5 x hi / low chimes an emergency!!!
>
> 2x bong!! for the seatbelt sign flashing for top of climb for crew to be released and same again for crew to be seated for landing!
>
> 3x Chimes if toilet smoke detector activated
>
> 1x Chime for toilet call bell 1x HIGH, HIGH LOW Chime for emergency Interphone call to Manager
>
> 1x LOW LOW HIGH Chime for Crew help needed!
>
> If you listen carefully the are two tones of call chime. A high and a
>   low. These will vary depending on operator and aircraft type!

This is confirmed again on [Airlines.net](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/read.main/27998/4/), where they show that for Canadian Airlines it's as follows:

> 1 bell - passenger call, lav call, change in cabin signs, five minute warning prior to landing, crew communication via interphone
>
> 2 bells - F/A to contact the flight deck for a message
>
> 3 bells - Take-off or landing imminent - take your jump seat
>
> 5 bells on the ground - evacuate
>
> 5 bells inflight - F/A to report immediately to the flight deck to receive emergency instructions

The same forums have [another page with information on NW, Continental and others](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/read.main/715569/4/), so it would certainly seem to vary from company to company.

Comment: Canadian Airlines ceased operations in 2001, suggesting that's not a super up-to-date resource

Comment: @KateGregory indeed, but it still shows the point that each airline has differed - there not being a standard.  Although I suppose hypothetically they could have been standardised since then, although the other links would seem to indicate not.

Comment: Great, now I'm going to be anxious whenever I hear 3 chimes in-flight because I'll be expecting to hear 2 more right afterwards.